# mvcHow can I create a dynamic dropdown list based on the users selection in codeigniter MVC

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

Im building a search function for a CMS. The CMS has been built using codeigniter mvc framework.

I currently have a search form where the user can select what database they want to search, this then populates a second dropdown list with the tables in this database, they can then enter any keywords they want to search into a search box then from this they can produce reports.

I have been tasked with extending this search feature. at the moment the dropdowns are populated from text files using this Javascript:

```
function search(Search_form){
    $("#dbase").change(function () {
        $("#second-choice").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
    });
}
```

Obviously the text files contain `<option>` replacements and the Javascript function populates them based on selection.

This is very inefficient as if new databases are added then I will have to create new text files with hundreds of rows of data!I would also like to add a feature where the user can select a column in a database so my question is how would I populate the dropdowns from a database?

So id like the dropdown selection to be:

DB->TBL->COL

Comment: 3 AJAX calls, 1) Return list of DB's, 2) Return list of Tables passing DB name/id, 3) Return col's of table passing DB name/id and Table name.

Comment: @garfbradaz don't add your own code. Original poster of the question (Sam in this case) should post **their code** so that we can help. And if somehow the OP contacted you with their code, ask them to add it themselves, by clicking "edit" link.

Comment: I didn't add my own code, I took it from the OP fiddle